# Iterate over multiple joined tables to display items in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an Order model, a LineItem model and a Product model.  Below are the associations.  I'm trying to figure out how to access the name attribute in the Product model.  My first thought was to iterate over the LineItem table to gather the line_items where order_id == order that is used in the show view.  Then, iterate over the new line_items and get each product name from the product_id attribute of the line_item.  This would have to be done in a method, probably in the Order model.  Is there a better way this can be done using Rails associations?  My current implementation results in undefined method product for #Order:0x007f5d007305f0

order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

  after_validation :set_amount

  private
  def set_amount
    self.amount = line_items.map(&:product).map(&:cost).inject(:+)
  end
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items
end
```

line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

order/show.html.erb

```
<h3>Customer - <%= @order.user.first_name %> <%= @order.user.last_name %></h3>
<h4>Order Date - <%= @order.created_at.to_s(:date_us) %></h4>

<%= @line_items.each do |item| %>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Quantity</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><%= item.order.product.name %></td>
                <td class="text-right"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
<div class="text-right">
  <h3><%= @order.amount %></h3>
</div>
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @orders = Order.all

  end

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.line_items.build
  end

  def create
    @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
    if @order.valid?
      @order.save
      redirect_to order_receipt_path(@order)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(line_items_attributes: [:id, :name, :product_id])
  end

  def products
    @products ||= Product.all
  end
  helper_method :products
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive the following error, because the `Order` model doesn't have `project` association, but the `LineItem` has.

You might want to filter the line items by order in the controller `show` method:

```
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @line_items = @order.line_items
end
```

And then iterate over them and display their project names:

```
<h3>Customer - <%= @order.user.first_name %> <%= @order.user.last_name %></h3>
<h4>Order Date - <%= @order.created_at.to_s(:date_us) %></h4>

<%= @line_items.each do |item| %>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Quantity</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><%= item.product.name %></td>
                <td class="text-right"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<% end %>
<div class="text-right">
  <h3><%= @order.amount %></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  I knew I was missing something.  I was trying to do much in the view when it really should have been handled in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Order doesn't know product. You should call `item.product.name` instead of `item.order.product.name`

Answer (score 0):

Also consider eager loading products to avoiding N+1 query problem. You can do this in the OrdersController#show action with: `@order.line_items.includes(:product)`